# Change dynamical directory on file:inbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration, citrus-framework

I'm new with Spring and I'm using [Citrus Framework](http://www.citrusframework.org/).
I'll try to change, dynamically, the `inbound-channel-adapter` `destination` variable. This variable is located in properties file and change all the time.

Currently I'm using an `AtomicReference` and I change its value in java code

In `context.xml` :

```
    <bean id="targetDir" class="java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference">
        <constructor-arg value="${output.path.temp}"/>
    </bean>

    <file:inbound-channel-adapter id="fileInboundAdapter" auto-create-directory="false"
        channel="fileChannel" directory="file:@targetDir.get()" auto-startup="false"
        filename-pattern="*.xml">
        <si:poller cron="0 * * * * ?"/>
    </file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

And in java file :

```
SourcePollingChannelAdapter fileInboundAdapter = (SourcePollingChannelAdapter)context.getApplicationContext().getBean("fileInboundAdapter");
if (fileInboundAdapter.isRunning()) {
    fileInboundAdapter.stop();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    AtomicReference<String> targetDir = (AtomicReference<String>)     
    context.getApplicationContext().getBean("targetDir", AtomicReference.class);
    targetDir.set(strOutPath[0]+"/"+strOutPath[1]+"/"+strOutPath[2]+"/"+strOutPath[3]+"/"); 
    fileInboundAdapter.start();
}
```

This solution don't works ... someone have any solutions ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's true. Because your `AtomicReference` doesn't have affect to the target `directory`.

You do this `directory="file:@targetDir.get()"`. It isn't correct at all, because this `String` will try to be converted to the `File` object. If you want to use here a SpEL it should be like this:

```
directory="#{targetDir.get()}"
```

without any `file:` prefix.

Anyway it doesn't help because that SpEL is evaluated only once at applicationContext strtup.

Since you are going to change the `directory` at runtime you should use `FileReadingMessageSource.setDirectory` from your service. Something like this:

```
SourcePollingChannelAdapter fileInboundAdapter = (SourcePollingChannelAdapter)context.getApplicationContext().getBean("fileInboundAdapter");
if (fileInboundAdapter.isRunning())
    fileInboundAdapter.stop();

    FileReadingMessageSource source = (FileReadingMessageSource) context.getApplicationContext().getBean("fileInboundAdapter.source");    
    source.setDirectory(new File(strOutPath[0]+"/"+strOutPath[1]+"/"+strOutPath[2]+"/"+strOutPath[3]+"/")); 
    fileInboundAdapter.start();
}
```

And get rid of that `AtomicReference`.

From the start you can use property-placeholder for the `directory` attribute directly.